# Copying a field and adding some text to it

Tags: php, mysql, copy, field

Hi I am trying to take the `gamename` field and put it into the `customTitle` field but add some text around it. So example is the game name is **Balloon Pop** in gamename I want **Play Balloon Pop Now - FlameGame.net**

If you need more Information write comments to this question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

--EDIT--

And here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM games";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");

    mysql_query("UPDATE games SET gameKeywords=tags");

    $title = array();
    $id = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $title[] = $row['gamename'];
        $id[] = $row['gameid'];
    }
    foreach($title as $Stitle){
        foreach($id as $Sid){
    mysql_query("UPDATE games SET customTitle = 'Play ".$Stitle." Now - FlameGame.net' WHERE gameid LIKE '".$Sid."'");


        }
    }

}
?>
```

In the `db` it replaces all of the `customTitles` to the name of the first game.

--EDIT--

I figured out a mysql command that dose exactly what this program is supposed to do.
Here it is:

```
UPDATE games SET customTitle = concat('Play ',gamename,' Now – FlameGame.net');
```

Comment: `SET` comes in first before `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE games SET customTitle = 'Play ".$Stitle." Now - FlameGame.net' WHERE gameid LIKE '".$Sid."'");
```